# Backbone.js fetch with parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Following the [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch), I did:

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ItemModel,
        url: '/Items'
})

collection.fetch({ data: { page: 1} });
```

the url turned out to be: `http://localhost:1273/Items?[object%20Object]`

I was expecting something like `http://localhost:1273/Items?page=1`

So how do I pass params in the fetch method?

Comment: That's definitely weird. What you have looks like it should work just fine, based on [the API docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch). Are you using the latest version of Backbone.js?

Comment: Can you try `JSON.stringify({ data: { page: 1} })`?

Comment: @Joe Tuskan, I'm not sure what to do with that, but I did: `collection.fetch(JSON.stringify({ data: { page: 1} }));` and nothing was passed in the url.

Comment: Ok, do this: collection.fetch({ data:JSON.stringify({ page: 1}) });

Comment: @Joe Tuskan, I got this: `http://localhost:1273/Items?{%22page%22:1}`, So I guess what I'm now looking for is converting json to url parameters. Else I'd have to just use a string.

Comment: `{ data: $.param({ page: 1}) }`

Comment: Thanks, this works, could you make it into an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: This works fine as you wrote it in Backbone 1.0 fyi

Answer (score 216, accepted):

changing:

```
collection.fetch({ data: { page: 1} });
```

to:

```
collection.fetch({ data: $.param({ page: 1}) });
```

So with out over doing it, this is called with your `{data: {page:1}}` object as `options`

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var type = methodMap[method];

    // Default JSON-request options.
    var params = _.extend({
      type:         type,
      dataType:     'json',
      processData:  false
    }, options);

    // Ensure that we have a URL.
    if (!params.url) {
      params.url = getUrl(model) || urlError();
    }

    // Ensure that we have the appropriate request data.
    if (!params.data && model && (method == 'create' || method == 'update')) {
      params.contentType = 'application/json';
      params.data = JSON.stringify(model.toJSON());
    }

    // For older servers, emulate JSON by encoding the request into an HTML-form.
    if (Backbone.emulateJSON) {
      params.contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      params.processData = true;
      params.data        = params.data ? {model : params.data} : {};
    }

    // For older servers, emulate HTTP by mimicking the HTTP method with `_method`
    // And an `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header.
    if (Backbone.emulateHTTP) {
      if (type === 'PUT' || type === 'DELETE') {
        if (Backbone.emulateJSON) params.data._method = type;
        params.type = 'POST';
        params.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', type);
        };
      }
    }

    // Make the request.
    return $.ajax(params);
};
```

So it sends the 'data' to [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which will do its best to append whatever `params.data` is to the URL.

Answer (score 71):

You can also set processData to true:

```
collection.fetch({ 
    data: { page: 1 },
    processData: true
});
```

Jquery will auto process data object into param string,

but in Backbone.sync function,
Backbone turn the processData off because Backbone will use other method to process data
in POST,UPDATE...

in Backbone source:

```
if (params.type !== 'GET' && !Backbone.emulateJSON) {
    params.processData = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example if you are using Titanium Alloy:

```
 collection.fetch({ 
     data: {
             where : JSON.stringify({
                page: 1
             })
           } 
      });
```

Comment: What is Titanium Alloy?

Comment: Alloy is an MVC framework for the Appcelerator Titanium SDK (https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy)

Answer (score -3):

```
try {
    // THIS for POST+JSON
    options.contentType = 'application/json';
    options.type = 'POST';
    options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);

    // OR THIS for GET+URL-encoded
    //options.data = $.param(_.clone(options.data));

    console.log('.fetch options = ', options);
    collection.fetch(options);
} catch (excp) {
    alert(excp);
}
```