# Why when I add data option to backbone model fetch, does it not trigger callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational, marionette

I'm doing a simple fetch with a model directly in backbone.

This works perfectly.

```
model.fetch({
        success: function () {
            alert("success");                
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error with data!!");
        },
        change: function () {
            alert("change");
        }
    });
```

However I want to sent a parameter with the request, but when I do this, it stops working? No errors reported?

```
model.fetch({ data: { userId: userId} },{
        success: function () {
            alert("success");                
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error with data!!");
        },
        change: function () {
            alert("change");
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help? The request looks like to goes and comes back from the server perfectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to have been answered before already.

[Backbone.js fetch with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659283/backbone-js-fetch-with-parameters)

Also I think you do not have to wrap your callback functions in a separate object, but they can be stored in the same one as the data variable.

Like this:

```
...fetch({data: $.param({...}), success: ..., error: ...});
```

Comment: Doh, so stupid of me. Obviously by doing it the way I was doing it, I was moving the location of the callbacks, so they couldn't be found.

Comment: I'm also not sure if there even exists a change callback for fetch. In the documentation they refer to a change event you can bind actions to.

Comment: "change" is automatically triggered on fetch if the server's state is different from the model's state.

Comment: I actually thought the same thing, I just chucked change in there in case it was something that was happening. So stupid of me!