# Fetch Backbone collection with search parameters

Tags: search, backbone.js, query-string

I'd like to implement a search page using `Backbone.js`. The search parameters are taken from a simple form, and the server knows to parse the query parameters and return a json array of the results. My model looks like this, more or less:

```
App.Models.SearchResult = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/search'
});

App.Collections.SearchResults = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.SearchResult
});

var results = new App.Collections.SearchResults();
```

I'd like that every time I perform `results.fetch()`, the contents of the search form will also be serialized with the `GET` request. Is there a simple way to add this, or am I doing it the wrong way and should probably be handcoding the request and creating the collection from the returned results:

```
$.getJSON('/search', { /* search params */ }, function(resp){
    // resp is a list of JSON data [ { id: .., name: .. }, { id: .., name: .. }, .... ]
    var results = new App.Collections.SearchResults(resp);

   // update views, etc.
});
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[Backbone.js fetch with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659283/backbone-js-fetch-with-parameters) answers most of your questions, but I put some here as well.

Add the `data` parameter to your `fetch` call, example:

```
var search_params = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': 'value3',
  ...
  'keyN': 'valueN',
};

App.Collections.SearchResults.fetch({data: $.param(search_params)});
```

Now your call url has added parameters which you can parse on the server side.

Comment: I agree. Search is normally done with a GET not a POST.  I see merits to the Search model `.save()` approach especially if you are using the server to log/store the searches, but this answer is more standard (and most people are using client-side javascript to track the searches anyway).

Comment: I had no idea about $.param OR about passing {data: ...} to the fetch call. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 13):

*Attention: code simplified and not tested*

I think you should split the functionality:

#### The Search Model

It is a proper *resource* in your server side. The only action allowed is `CREATE`.

```
var Search = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: "/search",

  initialize: function(){
    this.results = new Results( this.get( "results" ) );
    this.trigger( "search:ready", this );
  }
});
```

#### The Results Collection

It is just in charge of collecting the list of Result models

```
var Results = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Result
});
```

#### The Search Form

You see that this View is making the intelligent job, listening to the `form.submit`, creating a new `Search` object and sending it to the server to be `created`. This `created` mission doesn't mean the Search has to be stored in database, this is the normal `creation` behavior, but it does not  always need to be this way.  In our case `create` a Search means to search the DB looking for the concrete registers.

```
var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "submit form" : "createSearch"
  },

  createSearch: function(){
    // You can use things like this
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery
    // to authomat this process
    var search = new Search({
      field_1: this.$el.find( "input.field_1" ).val(),
      field_2: this.$el.find( "input.field_2" ).val(),
    });

    // You can listen to the "search:ready" event
    search.on( "search:ready", this.renderResults, this )

    // this is when a POST request is sent to the server
    // to the URL `/search` with all the search information packaged
    search.save(); 
  },

  renderResults: function( search ){
    // use search.results to render the results on your own way
  }
});
```

I think this kind of solution is very clean, elegant, intuitive and very extensible.

Answer (score 7):

Found a very simple solution - override the `url()` function in the collection:

```
App.Collections.SearchResults = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  urlRoot: '/search',

  url: function() {
    // send the url along with the serialized query params
    return this.urlRoot + "?" + $("#search-form").formSerialize();
  }
});
```

Hopefully this doesn't horrify anyone who has a bit more Backbone / Javascript skills than myself.

Comment: There is a little coupling here with this DOM reference into the Collection. But I have done uglier things :)

Comment: I'd say it was a fault of Backbone's that it's not easier to do this another way.

Comment: ^--> plus the accepted answer does the same, and relies on jQuery .val() instead of backbone's models.

Comment: This was the approach I was using until I saw @jakee's answer above.

Answer (score 7):

It seems the current version of Backbone (or maybe jQuery) automatically stringifies the `data` value, so there is no need to call `$.param` anymore.

The following lines produce the same result:

```
collection.fetch({data: {filter:'abc', page:1}});
collection.fetch({data: $.param({filter:'abc', page:1})});
```

The querystring will be `filter=abc&page=1`.

EDIT: This should have been a comment, rather than answer.

Comment: Helpful, nonetheless!