# How to search a Backbone collection with "any"?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

Yesterday I found a code to search a Backbone collection using a `any()` function rather that something like.

```
var myItem Collection.findWhere(...)
if (myItem)
{
}
```

But my file as been erased by TypeScript and "any" is such a vague keyword I can't find it back.

Comment: Hi i think this will solve your problems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315973/fetch-backbone-collection-with-search-parameters

Answer (score 4):

`any` is an alias of [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some). It's [mixed into Backbone.collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so
you can just do `collection.some()` or `collection.any()`