# How to give restful (nested) url in a collection in backbone.js?(Rails App)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

In my rails App I have nested routes as follow:-

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts do
  end
end
```

Suppose I need to fetch all the comments for a post of an individual user. I should make a use of fetch function for the collection of post.

```
class DemoApp.Collections.Posts extends Backbone.Collection
// here my url should consist of user_id  and action where the posts
// are being fetched.
url: "/users/user_id/posts"
```

For fetching the comments I should call fetch function on an object.

```
 posts = DemoApp.Collections.Posts 
 posts.fetch()
```

I am having problem in passing the user_id.

Gem used backbone-on-rails (0.9.2.1)

ruby version 1.9.3

rails version 3.2.1

Comment: what do you mean you have problems by specifying the user_id?

Comment: how do i  pass user_id in the url of posts collection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js fetch with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659283/backbone-js-fetch-with-parameters)

Comment: Passing parameters in fetch function will not put the user_id in url, instead it will append user_id at the end of url. Something like this:-  /users/undefined/posts?user_id="whatever the value is being passed"

Comment: If somehow the `user_id` is available in collection, you can specify `url` as a function in the collection, like `url : function() { return "/users/" + user_id + "/posts"; }`. Backbone will execute this function every time you do a `fetch` and will take that `url`. But only thing is `user_id` should be accessible in the collection with the appropriate value.